# FizzBuzz is it possible make my solution shorter?

Tags: javascript

I tried to make 3 conditions in one `array.forEach`, but this give me incorrect output. Is it possible to short my code to one `array.forEach`? Have 3 conditions inside it?

```
var array = []; // create empty array
for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
  array.push(i); // write in array all values of i, each iteration
}

array.forEach((number) => {
  if (array[number] % 3 === 0 && array[number] % 5 === 0) {
    array[number] = "FizzBuzz";
  }
});

array.forEach((number) => { //  
  if (array[number] % 3 === 0) {
    array[number] = "Fizz";
  }
});

array.forEach((number) => {
  if (array[number] % 5 === 0) {
    array[number] = "Buzz";
  }
});

for (let i = 0; i < array.length; i++) { //output array elements
  console.log(array[i]);
}
```

Comment: [if...else](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else)

Comment: You need to do the "FizzBuzz" loop last, not first. And yes, you can combine them into a single `forEach`.

Comment: @Ken Y-N I need to write conditions one by one ? But this not work correct. And dont understand about loop, we are talking about conditions :)










`if (array[number] % 3 === 0 ) {

    array[number] = "Fizz";
}
if (array[number] % 5 === 0 ) {

    array[number] = "Buzz";

} 
if (array[number] % 3 === 0 && array[number] % 5 === 0) {  

    array[number] = "FizzBuzz";
}`

Comment: It is going to be much shorted with less newlines...

Comment: @KenY-N Dont understand how to write this. Can you help me ?

Comment: @VLAZ Give me a break! I am new here. Mistake with formatting, i'll work on it :)

Comment: The question was posted more than 40 minutes ago and you didn't. I suppose if I didn't mention it you wouldn't have acknowledged the bad formatting. Ideally you should have made it presentable *before* even posting. Failing that, you shouldn't have waited 40 minutes for somebody to remark on the bad formatting before trying to do something.

Answer (score 0):

First pointer: that's a lot of whitespace.

Second pointer, rather than creating an array then cycling through that array, you can do it all in one loop, using the `if....else` block; something like this:

```
for (var i = 1; i < 101; i++) {
   if (i % 3 === 0 && i % 5 === 0) {  
        console.log("FizzBuzz");
   }
   else if (i % 3 === 0) {
        console.log("Fizz");
   }
   else if (i % 5 === 0) {
        console.log("Buzz");
   }
   else {
        console.log(i);
   } 
}
```

Comment: Yeah. It one of all methods for solve this problem. It can exist, but i try to short my solution ) Thanks for give other solution

Answer (score 0):

You are "walking over" the Array multiple times.

IMHO the most important Array Method to learn is **Map**:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map

Which "walks over" the Array and **returns** a new value for that Array index

```js
let arr = Array(100)
  .fill((x, div, label) => x % div ? "" : label) //store Function in every index
  .map((func, idx) =>
    func(++idx, 3, "Fizz") + func(idx, 5, "Buzz") || idx
  );
document.body.append(arr.join(", "));
```

`fill` takes a **single** Object, it is not executed 100 times!
Since JavaScript Functions are Objects this code **declares** a function **once**

Note the `++idx` because we want to start at 1, not 0

In JavaScript `""+""` is a Falsy value, thus it returns the `idx` value for non-FizzBuzz numbers

More Array Methods explained: https://array-methods.github.io